# Time resolution of Chrome DevTools performance flame chart

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I profiled the execution of some Javascript code with Chrome DevTools. Here is an extract of the resulting flamechart:

[image]

There are many small blocks with seemingly identical sizes. When I hover over them, they all claim to take 0.16 ms. This makes me suspicious:

Do they actually all take 0.16 ms, or is 0.16 ms rather the smallest time resolution in DevTools?

Comment: Try enabling higher resolution in devtools settings https://puu.sh/F8KQR/614cf66cb9.png

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked, and it's already enabled.